# Почему когда в php вызываю exec в цикле в исполняемой программе добавляются аргументы

Tags: php, python, консоль

Не могу понять почему происходит следующее. Когда в php в цикле вызываю функцию exec и передаю параметр в python вот так:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    $cmd = 'C:\Users\Stubert\python.exe E:\web\www\test.py param_'.$i;
    exec($cmd, $output);
    print_r($output);
}
```

И принимаю эти параметры:

```
import sys
args = sys.argv
args.pop(0)
print(args)
```

В переменной $output оказывается вот это

```
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_0']
)
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_0']
    [1] => ['param_1']
)
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_0']
    [1] => ['param_1']
    [2] => ['param_2']
)
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_0']
    [1] => ['param_1']
    [2] => ['param_2']
    [3] => ['param_3']
```

Я ожидаю получить параметры примерно так

```
    Array
(
    [0] => ['param_0']
)
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_1']
)
Array
(
    [0] => ['param_2']
)
    Array
(
    [0] => ['param_3']
)
```

Как правильно сделать, чтобы параметры не добавлялись а заменялись и почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Затестил сам :<, да, щас скапитаню, если скажу что в массив `дописывается информация` а связано это с принципом работы `exec`

Поможет нам как всегда документация:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

> Обратите внимание, что если массив уже содержит какие-либо элементы,
>   то exec() добавит новые элементы в конец массива. Если же вы не
>   хотите, чтобы функция добавляла новые элементы в конец, вызовите
>   unset() на этом массиве, прежде чем передать его в exec().

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже уже разобрался, плохо смотрел документацию. Можно еще вызвать другую функцию, вот так: $output = shell_exec($cmd); print_r($output);